# what's the arguments of python's struct.Struct()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have seen some usages of `struct.Struct`, with parameters I understand. `struct.Struct('I3sf')` means that the struct contains an integer, three strings and a float.

There are some usages of `struct.Struct`, for example `,struct.Struct('!I')`, where I'm not sure what it means. Is there any comprehensive documentation on `struct.Struct`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html#struct-format-strings), the `!` means that bytes are stored in network byte order, which is big-endian.

Comment: and a annotation added is that struct.Struct('!i') means that messages up to 2**32 -1 in length.What does it mean?